# Reduce MySQL Code down or combine SELECT Statements

Tags: mysql

I have made a few relations to do with a banking database system.
this is my current code. The table has

```
SELECT COUNT(AccountType) AS Student_Total FROM Account
WHERE AccountType ='Student' 
and SortCode = 00000001;
SELECT COUNT(AccountType) AS Student_Total FROM Account
WHERE AccountType ='Student' 
and SortCode = 00000002;
SELECT COUNT(AccountType) AS Student_Total FROM Account
WHERE AccountType ='Student' 
and SortCode = 00000003;
```

the rest of the code is a duplicate of this part with the next type of 'Account' and looping back through sortcode's 1-3 again.

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of producing this. I need to count the number of student, current and saver accounts for each bank.

Or is there a way to combine lots of selects together to make a neat table?

Comment: Can you also post an `show create table Account` output? because you dont want to use an GROUP BY on an non indexed column..

Answer (score 2):

That's what `GROUP BY` is for!

```
SELECT SortCode,COUNT(AccountType) AS Student_Total FROM Account
WHERE AccountType ='Student' 
GROUP BY SortCode;
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also `GROUP BY` with multiple grouping fields:

```
SELECT SortCode,AccountType,COUNT(AccountType) AS Student_Total FROM Account
GROUP BY SortCode,AccountType;
```

Comment: So how do I apply this to 9 SELECT Statements?

Comment: You don't have to - this creates a single table with a row for each `SortCode`.

Comment: Right! So if we take this Query and repeat it 3 times, each time changing Student to Saver or Current how to we combine all of these 3 tables?

Comment: `GROUP BY` allows you to have as many group fields as you want. I'll update the answer with example code.

Comment: +1 but I would delete the first query. It's clear to me OP always wanted the second one

Comment: @Bohemian I'll leave the first query as an example for using `GROUP BY` together with `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You could also apply a PIVOT approach to this query to always return a single row and know the fixed-final columns of the result set.  However, applying a group by allows for more flexibility of returned rows, especially if you have a large amount of individual things you are trying to tally up.

```
select
      A.AccountType,
      SUM( IF( A.SortCode = 1, 1, 0 )) as SortCode1Cnt,
      SUM( IF( A.SortCode = 2, 1, 0 )) as SortCode2Cnt,
      SUM( IF( A.SortCode = 3, 1, 0 )) as SortCode3Cnt
   from
      Account A
   where
      A.AccountType = 'Student'
      AND A.SortCode IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
   group by
      A.AccountType
```

Note... it appears your sort code is a numeric as you have no quotes around indicating a character string.  So, all the leading zeros are irrelevant.  And if you were only doing based on a single Account Type, you don't even need the leading Account Type column and can remove the group by too.